# Why does a vuetify image have "padding-bottom: 200%"? And how do I make it smaller?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify's `<v-img>` bewilders me. I've got the following:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-row no-gutters class="flex-grow-0 justify-end">
        <router-link class="ma-8" to="/">Home</router-link>
        <router-link class="ma-8" to="/">Features</router-link>
        <router-link class="ma-8" to="/">About</router-link>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>

    <v-main>
      <router-view />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
};
</script>
```

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-container class="center">
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12" sm="8" class="d-flex flex-column justify-center">
        <h1 class="text-h3 text-md-h1">Insert catchy phrase here.</h1>
      </v-col>
      <v-col
        cols="12"
        sm="4"
        class="d-flex flex-column justify-center align-center"
      >
        <v-img max-height="100%" contain src="../assets/iphone.png"></v-img>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Home",

  components: {},
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.center {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
</style>
```

My code produces this:
[image: The layout looks great on desktop]

The desktop layout looks great, but when the screen size is smaller, the image wraps and becomes too big.

The **desired behavior** is for this image to shrink when it wraps so that it still fits inside the viewport. But instead the image is big and extends beyond the viewport.

[image]

Upon closer inspection I found that `<v-img>` is to blame for this strange behavior. Inside of the `v-responsive__sizer` is this line of styling: `padding-bottom: 200%;`. When I uncheck this, my image shrinks to fit inside the container and things look like I want them to.

Anyone here familiar enough with vuetify to help me understand how I can achieve my desired behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Best thing would be to do a media query in your styles, so that your app is fully responsive. Otherwise, you can affect that specific vuetify class in your styles. It would look like this: .v-responsive__sizer (or any class you found on the inspect) { padding-bottom: 0% !important} (or any padding you want).